# Prove that we can not get a rectangle in the coloured region which has no side on the X-axis but all vertices on the boundary?

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus

Can anyone help me to prove that we can not get a rectangle in the coloured region which has no side on the X-axis but all vertices on the boundary ?

[image]

It is quite clear from the figure . But I can not prove it mathematically.

I was given to find the area of the rectangle with biggest permeter lying in that coloured region. Intuitively , I knew that we can not form a rectangle with three vertices on the curve and one on the X-axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that the graph of *y* = sin(*x*)? Suppose there is such a rectangle. It follows from your conditions that no more than one of the vertices may lie on the *x*-axis. That means that there must be at least three vertices on the sine curve, which means there must be at least one angle inscribed in that curve. Prove that every chord must have a gradient greater than -1 and less than 1. Therefore the product of gradients of two intersecting chords cannot be -1, hence no right angle.

Comment: This suggests a way to make the question moire interesting: For which $k>0$ can we find such rectangle a rectangle if we work with $y=k\sin x$ instead?

Comment: Yes. This is the graph of y = sinx.If you elaborate more on this , it will be great.@Pope

Comment: "... there must be at least one *RIGHT* angle inscribed in that curve. ..."

Comment: Thank you very much. I was stuck on a problem for not seeing this. Nobody except you helped me. Everybody tried to close the question.@Pope